# Controlling LED drivers with a PWM using a PIC MCU

Tags: led, pic, pwm, driver

In one of the circuits I'm working on, there are three LED's connected to every LED driver output (I have a space and cost constraint because of which I need to use this). The high side of each LED is connected to a fixed high voltage and I provide the ground using the LED driver to switch on and off the LED's.
The three LED's have different switching on voltages using which I want to switch on each LED one after another. Is it possible to provide a PWM signal to the LED driver such that I can have the output as 3,2 and 1 Volt respectively?

As in the schematic, LED's H20, H12 and H4 have different switching on voltages. Vcc1, Vcc2 and Vcc3 have the same potential. I want the three LED's to switch on one after the other.

[image: The schematic that I'm working with]

Comment: Siddharth Goel - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules differ from typical forums. (b) Please link to device datasheets. (c) Please [edit] & use Ctrl+G on a PC (or click "picture of mountains" icon on a touch screen) to upload an image of your existing or proposed schematic, showing the LED driver, the LEDs and the relevant connections & power rail(s). (d) FYI it's unclear to me from your question, how much of the design is already decided and what can be changed. I recommend you clarify when you edit the question & add the schematic & datasheet links. TY

Comment: Do your LEDs have built-in resistors?  If not, how do you propose to limit current?

Comment: @Siddharth Can you provide an English version of the datasheet for the SM16306SJ? But if my assumption is correct, that this is a constant current sink device, then the answer is *no*.